# Database-Trigger to Delete row where condition True:

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I need trigger That Deletes row where in table `paym` both columns `table1` and `table2` are not empty.

Example in tables below:
table: `paym`

```
 ID        username        table1        Table2  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   1   |  John       |  Value      |    Value  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  Alex       |  Null       |    Null   |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Condition is True: After Deleted row:

```
 ID        username        table1        Table2  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  Alex       |  Null       |    Null   |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

**My attemp is:** (Not working)

```
CREATE trigger DeleteROW
AFTER UPDATE ON paym
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.table1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.table2 IS NOT NULL) THEN
          DELETE
    FROM
        paym WHERE table1 and table2 IS NOT NULL ;
        END IF;
    END
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that in a `before update` or `after update` trigger.

Comment: @danb Any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger cannot modify the table it is running on.

You should create a stored procedure to handle this, and call that instead of the `DELETE` command...